# Remove key with empty array value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When I have one item left in an array and I remove it, the field becomes empty. Is there any option to check if there is one element left and then update the key with `undefined` instead of removing?

Here is what I have:

```js
User.aggregate([
    {$match: {email: {$in: [email, friendEmail]}}},
    {
      $project: {
        friendSentRequests: {$size: {"$ifNull": ["$friendSentRequests", []]}},
        friendReceivedRequests: {$size: {"$ifNull": ["$friendReceivedRequests", []]}},
      }
    }],
  (err, result) => { ... }
);
```

With method written above I indeed get the array size, but `batch` throws errors that array is type `missing` if one doc doesn't  have the key that second doc has. Unless I'm not supposed to make any updates in `(err, result) => {..}` function and there is another recommended way to update the object.

I don't want to set `multi` because I want to update via `batch` two different keys from different docs and I can't get the array length of each of these fields. Unless I'm misunderstanding how `multi` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to confirm the number of elements in an array , e.g here is you want to check that the array has one element then:

```
{
    $match:{
      "myArray" :{ $size : 1 }
    }
}
```

And to check if array does not exist:

```
   {
    $match:{
      "myArray" :{ $exists: false}
    }
}
```